# Angular variable not updating on Blur-admin template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Blur-admin template but I can not figure out why when I update angular variable it is not updating inside ba-panel. for example:

```
<div class="widgets">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

  <div ba-panel ba-panel-title="Editable Cells" ba-panel-class="with-scroll">
      {{foodTableData}}
    <div include-with-scope="app/pages/FoodMenu/foodTable.html"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

foodTableData is not getting updated in the interface

I'm using this code to update the variable:

```
   $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.foodTableData = mdata;});   
console.log($rootScope.foodTableData[0].title); 
 $scope.$apply(); 
 console.log("foodData ", $scope.foodTableData);
```

And the log is showing the data just fine, but the interface is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue could be related to scope nesting.
try using dot access to variable  inside templates and controllers like

```
$rootScope.obj.foodTableData = [{title: '123'}];
$rootScope.obj.foodTableData[0].title;
```

easiest way to protect agains these errors - controllerAs syntax

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the widget "ba-panel" in div: `<div ba-panel> {{myScope}} </div>`.

But I do not know why the Blur-admin can not read the `{{myScope}}` inside do "ba-panel", when loaded later by a $http, for example.

So, I had to remove the "ba-panel".